# Issue with Drag&Drop support within a tab on RedHat 5

Tags: java, tabs, drag-and-drop, swt, jface

I've got an issue with the drag and drop support for my tree items within a tab, the simple piece of code below works well on Windows XP/Seven, Ubuntu, Fedora and RedHat 4 but fails on RedHat 5.

```
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    setShellStyle(getShellStyle() | SWT.RESIZE);

    TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(composite, SWT.NONE);
    tabFolder.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    TabItem tab = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tab.setText("TabName");

    /*
     * TabItem 1 Content:
     */
    TreeViewer tree = new TreeViewer(tabFolder, SWT.SINGLE|SWT.BORDER);
    tree.setLabelProvider(provider);
    tree.setContentProvider(provider);
    tree.getTree().setHeaderVisible(true);
    tree.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    TreeColumn tc = new TreeColumn(tree.getTree(), SWT.NONE, 0);
    tc.setText("Name");
    tc.setWidth(100);
    tab.setControl(tree.getTree());

    tree.setInput(provider.getInput());

    /*
     * Drag&Drop Support
     */
    Transfer[] transfers = new Transfer[] { TextTransfer.getInstance()};
    DragDropItemsSupport dndItemsListener = new DragDropItemsSupport(tree);
    tree.addDragSupport(DND.DROP_MOVE, transfers, dndItemsListener);
    tree.addDropSupport(DND.DROP_MOVE, transfers, dndItemsListener);

    return composite;
}
```

When I said "works well", I'm able to pass through the method dragOver of ViewerDropAdapter on mentioned hosts.

```
@Override
public void dragOver(DropTargetEvent event) {
    if (event.item != null)
        System.out.println("Drag over : " + ((TreeItem)event.item).getText());
}
```

Is someone has a explanation, a way to investigate, or a solution :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the same thing on a TableViewer in a TabItem in a TabFolder on Centos 5.  Haven't tested on other OS.  Can be fixed by changing to CTabFolder and CTabItem.

Comment: Disturbing to be constrained to use a non-native implementation of tabs in order to take the benefit of DnD feature... Anyway it works :)